# redirect all html get requests to get files from ROOT/frontEnd folder instead of ROOT on Tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, url-rewriting, tomcat7

I want to move my HTML files and resources to ROOT/frontEnd on a tomcat 7

When I use the link [www.xyz.com/index.html](http://www.xyz.com/index.html) I want it to return the ROOT/frontEnd/index.html
without changing the URL to [www.xyz.com/frontEnd/index.html](http://www.xyz.com/frontEnd/index.html)
and without moving WEB-INF and META-INF folders.

The directory would look as follows

```
 - RooT
   - WEB-INF
   - META-INF
   - frontEnd
     - index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

While you could create a servlet registered to / (process all your requests) and deliver content from one subdirectory only, such functionality has been programmed and added to Tomcat already.

Have you tried the rewrite valve? https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/rewrite.html

Comment: I'm using tomcat 7 which doesn't support this type of rewrite rule.
I'm going to update my question.

Answer (score 0):

@HiranCaudhuri has a good answer but, as you say, it is not present in Tomcat 7. If you are not able to upgrade to a later version of Tomcat (which you might want to consider), you can use [Tuckey's url-rewrite filter](https://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) which has existed for a very long time and is very fully-featured.